# Laravel function does not exists

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some problems with my Laravel APP.
I'm using laravel 8 and every time when I try to visit home page it gives me like:

> Function () does not exist

This is how my routes looks like:

```
Route::get('/{any}', [VueController::class])->where('any', '.*');
```

And here how VueController looks like:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\User;
    
    class VueController extends Controller
    {
        public function __invoke()
        {
            return view('application');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because function doesnot exist on your route `VueController::class`

Answer (score 0):

`VueController::class` second parameter is missing  it should be

```php
Route::get('/{any}', [VueController::class,'index'])->where('any', '.*');`
```

then in controller

```php
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\User;
    
    class VueController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            return view('application');
        }
    }
```

---

`Route::get()` get req second array must have function name like  `[VueController::class,'index']`

if you don't want to mention `index` then in resouncse it is possible but it generate some url with some function it will not work in `__invoke()`

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing